# Commerce Customizable Products

Tags: commerce

I hope I could receive some help concerning Commerce Customizable Products. I am looking for a possibility to, when adding a product, selecting the options a customer could add on the 'add to card form'.

For example: Pizza A can have the toppings X, Y and Z. However, Pizza B can only have the toppings Y and Z.

How do I manage, when I add the pizzas to my store, that I can select which supplements can be added? When I have 100 pizza's, I can configure the toppings, but don't have to have 100 different taxonomy lists.

I hope my question is clear. I have watched Josh Miller his screencast on YouTube about customizable orders.

Kind regards,
Tim

Answer (score 0):

The only workable solution that I've come up with sits in a feature request in that module's issue queue; I haven't had a chance to try it out yet. Basically, I believe you can use a field on the product type as an options mask for the same field on the line item type. When a field is present on a line item type and shown on the Add to Cart form, its options will typically default to whatever is in the field settings. However, if you put that same field on the product type as a multi-value field, you could then use a form alter of the Add to Cart form to only show the options on the Add to Cart form that were selected for the product.

Again, this is just an idea - not implemented yet. But it seems like a very feasible way to accomplish what you want (and it's based on some architecture I actually helped a community member implement during a cocktail reception at DrupalCon Munich ; ).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The idea sounds wonderful. Making a list of available options which could form the possible variations, with the price effect included. For now I will continue without the Customizable Products module, as I need to customize the options per product entry.